# Create an SSRS Report using a CSV Data Source (overcome x86 vs x64 issues)

Tags: csv, reporting-services

We are currently using SSRS Report Server 2012. Users have Windows 2010 64 bit PCs and our servers are mostly Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 servers. This is what I have to work with, this can't be changed.

I have a CSV file on a 2008 server that I want to create a RAP Report on, however I am having no luck. The CSV file is built using a powershell script that extracts certain data from a heap of xml files. I've copied the CSV to my PC to test with first.

So far, errors have consisted of at least the following, probably more:

- The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified. (rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting)
- Cannot create a connection to data source 'dsOleDbCsvFile'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
- ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

How do I create an SSRS Report with a CSV data source (without the x86 vs x64 issues) that actually works please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are three quite different errors. What method are you currently using to access CSV from SSRS? Something like this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b66098a-9fec-4f29-8223-1e306d4c854b/using-a-csv-file-within-the-reporting-server-as-a-data-source-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Or this? http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/01/how-to-use-cvs-file-as-data-source-in.html

Comment: Yes, very different errors as I've tried various suggestions after scouring google. I saw those 2 URLs previously.
1 = loading a file into ReportServer db itself if I'm not mistaken. Not what I want to do.

Comment: 2 = did not work for me. When I create the dataset in Report Builder & click 'Refresh Fields', the fields are called F1, F2, etc instead of per Line 1 in the CSV.
Then when I try to run the new report in ReportServer, it errors with "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'blah'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: If you're going to use CSV file you'll need to prepare for a lot of crashes. The slightest thing wring with the file (too many commas, unexpected data value) and it won't work. With regards to F1, F2 etc. you need to set your ODBC connection up correctly. https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/3066882

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of accessing CSV files, as you have probably found out during your testing.

You could setup a linked server to the file, this might require a few config changes on your server though and you might have to install additional drivers on the server.

Another option would be to bulk insert your CSV file into a temp table and then return the results of the temp table to your report , do all this in your dataset query, so to SSRS it just looks like you've read a table.

There's an old but very good blog post on the subject below. Most of the blog is the problems with other methods, towards the end the author explains what he ended up doing and even supplied a script for an SP to help resolve the common issues with reading CSV files.

https://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2011/01/so-you-want-to-read-csv-files-huh.html

Search for the term "Another approach… much easier…" if you don't want to read it all, although it's worth reading just to understand the limitations of other approaches.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get the RAP report working using a CSV not a database table. Bulk Insert functionality is turned off so I don't have permission to use it. I'm having driver issues assuming due to x86 vs x64 issues. Besides the fact the Powershell version we have on the server is 2.0 and I don't have permission to install a later version so the csv column headings are in unsorted order & I don't know which order they will be in each time the csv is built.